# Testing Rails views in RSpec: why does it route to "show" when I want to test "index"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, rspec

I have this very basic view spec in `spec/views/users/index_spec.rb`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "users/index", type: :view do
  before(:each) do
    @user = create(:user)
    assign(:users, [@user])
  end

  it "renders a list of users" do
    render
    expect(page).to have_selector "tr##{dom_id(@user)}"
  end
end
```

When executing it, it's telling me the following:

```
Failures:

  1) users/index renders a list of users
     Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil, :locale=>#<User id: 1, name: "Rosalinda Dach", email: "marilie@leffler.ca", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$G/z6lbFUpnh9FD3bymYBE.LrJK3acKr4TsURgCq7B77...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2015-06-03 14:33:11", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, created_at: "2015-06-03 14:33:12", updated_at: "2015-06-03 14:33:12", avatar: nil>} missing required keys: [:id]
     # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:46:in `generate'
     # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:727:in `generate'
     # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:758:in `generate'
     # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:801:in `url_for'
     # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:280:in `call'
     # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@a4aa2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:345:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
```

Why does the test route to `users#show` instead of `users#index`?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code:

```
RSpec.describe "users/index.html.erb", type: :view do
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't find a suitable solution, I decided to create my own online Markdown editor with copy and paste: PIMP (**P**asteable **I**mages, **M**arkdown, **P**andoc).

http://pimp.suhail.uberspace.de/en

It's not yet looking very great yet, but it offers everything you need to create semantically awesome documents using Pandoc's very powerful Markdown, paste images directly from clipboard into the text, and export the documents to various formats (at the time being Docx, Epub, Odt, maybe later also PDF).

At the time being, to use PIMP, one has to create a user account.

The whole project is rather a proof of concept than a real project, but if people like and use it, I would be happy to make it a real project.